# How to clone rule in mongodb validations

Tags: mongodb, validation, bson, mongodb-compass

I have a large rule for 3 columns and I want to preventing from duplicating rule for every column, Have any one any idea to clone rule for every columns ? like enum values but for validation.

mongodb version : `4.2`

mongodb compass: `1.21.2`

example rule :

```
route_line: {
        bsonType: 'object',
        required: [
          'path',
          'stations'
        ],
        properties: {
          path: {
            bsonType: [
              'array'
            ],
            items: [
              {
                bsonType: [
                  'array'
                ],
                minItems: 2,
                maxItems: 2,
                items: [
                  {
                    bsonType: 'double',
                    minimum: -180,
                    maximum: 180
                  },
                  {
                    bsonType: 'double',
                    minimum: -90,
                    maximum: 90
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          stations: {
            bsonType: [
              'array'
            ],
            items: {
              bsonType: 'objectId'
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

other columns : `base_route_line`, `return_route_line`

Comment: Is this the schema?

Comment: @ParthShah its part of schema, the `route_line` validation schema

Comment: Using the shell, when you create a collection, you could add a validator like so:  `db.createCollection("base_route_line", { validator: validatorObject ... ` Save the validator object first.

Comment: @ParthShah yes, I saved that role and I already use it, but I think is there a way to create custom validator to use it in any collection columns ?